# Creating and returning a local variable inside a function within a function not working numpy

Tags: python, function, numpy, broadcast

I am trying to match array dimensions for a piece of work. I am trying to create and return a variable inside a function but i recieve the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'first' referenced before assignment
```

I don't understand this since the first encounter of the word is actually me defining what it is.

I cannot use `global` as it is a function inside a function. My code is as follow and should be reproducible.

```
a= np.array([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (10,11,12)])
b = np.array([(10, 20, 30), (40, 50, 60)])
def broadcast(a, b):
    def match_lengths(a_ar, b_ar):
        a_shape = list(np.shape(a_ar))
        b_shape = list(np.shape(b_ar))
        if len(a_shape) == len(b_shape):
            print('Already same dimensions')
            pass
        else:
            if len(a_shape) > len(b_shape):
                extra_dims = len(a_shape) - len(b_shape)
                smaller_arr = b_shape
            else:
                extra_dims = len(b_shape) - len(a_shape)
                smaller_arr = a_shape
            dim = (1,)
            add_dims = dim * extra_dims
            shapes = add_dims + tuple(smaller_arr)


            if smaller_arr == a_shape:
                first = np.reshape(a_ar, shapes)
            else:
                second = np.reshape(b_ar, shapes)
        return first, second

     match_lengths(a, b)
     a_shape = list(np.shape(first))
     b_shape = list(np.shape(second)) 
     return a_shape, b_shape
```

Does anyone understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

can you try the following, because `return first, second` is trying to return a vriable that was not initialized.

```
a= np.array([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (10,11,12)])
b = np.array([(10, 20, 30), (40, 50, 60)])
def broadcast(fun, a, b):

    def match_lengths(a_ar, b_ar):
        first, second = np.array([]), np.array([])
        a_shape = list(np.shape(a_ar))
        b_shape = list(np.shape(b_ar))
        if len(a_shape) == len(b_shape):
            print('Already same dimensions')
            pass
        else:
            if len(a_shape) > len(b_shape):
                extra_dims = len(a_shape) - len(b_shape)
                smaller_arr = b_shape
            else:
                extra_dims = len(b_shape) - len(a_shape)
                smaller_arr = a_shape
            dim = (1,)
            add_dims = dim * extra_dims
            shapes = add_dims + tuple(smaller_arr)


            if smaller_arr == a_shape:
                first = np.reshape(a_ar, shapes)
            else:
                second = np.reshape(b_ar, shapes)
        return first, second

     first, second = match_lengths(a, b)
     a_shape = list(np.shape(first))
     b_shape = list(np.shape(second)) 
     return a_shape, b_shape
```

Comment: NameError: name 'first' is not defined

Comment: i have updated the code, can you try now. if you are again getting an error, kindly share the entire traceback

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using the values returned by your function?

```
first, second = match_lengths(a, b)
```

This is normal function usage.  If the function returns some values, you assign them to variables.